# Exclude string from named capturing group result

Tags: regex

Given is the following Regex:

`^(?<side>(?:buy|sell)\s)(?<symbol>[A-Za-z0-9]+\s)(?P<at>at\s[A-Za-z0-9.]+\s)?(?P<stop>stop\s[A-Za-z0-9.]+\s)?(?P<risk>risk\s[A-Za-z0-9.]+)?$`

It matches:

- buy US500
- buy US500 at 4000
- buy US500 at 4000 stop 3000
- buy US500 at 4000 stop 3000 risk 400
- ...

The keys "at", "stop" and "risk" are optional.

The matching works fine, but the group results of "at", "stop" and "risk" contain the "at", "stop" and "risk" string as well. I only want to the value after the string.

- Instead of "stop 3000" I just want 3000.
- Instead of "risk 400" I just want 400.

[image]

Comment: Change `(?P<at>at\s[A-Za-z0-9.]+\s)?` to `(?:at\s(?P<at>[A-Za-z0-9.]+)\s)?` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the groups, convert the optional named groups to unnamed non-capturing ones and only capture into the named groups what you need:

```
^(?<side>buy|sell)\s+(?<symbol>[A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\s+at\s+(?P<at>[A-Za-z0-9.]+))?(?:\s+stop\s+(?P<stop>[A-Za-z0-9.]+))?(?:\s+risk\s+(?P<risk>[A-Za-z0-9.]+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXvGgx/2).

Note the `\s+` are used at the start of the optional non-capturing groups, it is more optimal to place them there.

In general, the change looks like `(?P<stop>stop\s[A-Za-z0-9.]+)?` => `(?:stop\s+(?P<stop>[A-Za-z0-9.]+))?` and all `\s` at the end of the former optional named groups are moved as `\s+` to the start of the optional non-capturing groups.